# how to test that right database is being used without actually querying database

Tags: database

I want to know when an application is pointing to a database, how to make sure that it is the correct database.
Can you let me know this from a Developer, DBA and a tester perspectives?

is it the database connection string? or update date on tables entries? any database scripts related check?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What type of application?

Comment: Its a web based application. there could be many test environments, and a production environment.

Comment: It is c# & .Net application.

Answer (score 1):

From a developer perspective, checking the connection string is the typical way to tell which database an application is pointing to. Of course, the big thing to look out for with this is making sure that you're looking at the right connection string, especially if you are using more than one of them in that application.

Depending on your application, you should be able to print a debugging message near your code that initializes the connection to the database that prints out the connection string that is being used for that connection. This could also allow the tester to know which database is being accessed.

From a DBA perspective, profiling the server could show active connections and/or queries with various amounts of detail depending on the database server being used.

Comment: Thank you. Anything from tester point of view?

Comment: I tried to address that a little bit in my second paragraph. If the connection string is exposed in a configuration file, then obviously the testers could look at that if they can access the system hosting the application. Otherwise, they could rely on the developers to print debugging info showing them which connection string the application was using to access the database.